# square root in $Z_n^*$

Tags: number-theory

Let $n$, $x$ be two numbers s.t. $x \in Z_n^*$. And lets assume there exists $y$ s.t. $y^2=x$ (mod n). Is it true that this implies that $y \in Z_n^*$? and if so, how can I show it ($gcd(n,y)=1$)?

Comment: If $y^2$ is invertible, then so is $y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x\in\Bbb Z_n^*\Longleftrightarrow (x,n)=1$$

Now, suppose $\,\exists\,y\in\Bbb Z_n\,\,s.t.\,\,y^2=x\,$ , and suppose further that

$$(y,n)=d\Longrightarrow n=ad\,,\,y=bd\Longrightarrow y^2=b^2d^2=x\Longrightarrow (x,n)\ge d$$

and from the above it follows at once that $\,(y,n)=d=1\Longleftrightarrow y\in\Bbb Z_n^*\,$

Comment: Is that also true when $y^2=x$ (mod n) but $y^2 \neq x$?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question: do you mean "...but $\,y^2\neq x\,$"... in $\,\Bbb Z\,$? If so then yes, of course, since the proof given above applies for $\,\Bbb Z_n\,$ and thus also for the integers (which I still am not sure why would be important for you...)

Answer (score 0):

From the fact that $y^2 = x$ is a unit we know there exists an inverse $u y^2 \equiv 1^2 \pmod n$.

From the fact that quadratic residues form a subgroup of the units group and that a residue times a non-residue is a non-residue we deduce that $u$ is a quadratic residue so $y$ is a unit.

**Theorem** A residue times non-residue is a non-residue in the units group.
*proof*: Let $n$ be a non-residue, suppose $r^2 n = u^2$ then $n = (r^{-1} u)^2$.